# How to compose same widget multiple times in a page

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a widget say `widget/userInfo`

And I using `compose`, I load this widget multiple times in my view as shown below:

**index.js:**

```
activate() {
  this.widget = {
        model: 'widgets/userinfo/viewmodel',
        view: 'widgets/userinfo/view.html',
        activationData: { userId: 1 }
    };
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    UserInfo: <div id="1" data-bind="compose: $root.userInfo"></div>
    UserInfo-2: <div id="2" data-bind="compose: $root.userInfo"></div>
</div>
```

When I compose the same widget multiple times like above, it only loads for the last div having id="2". But I want to load it for both divs

I googled it for this issue, but I couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about [Durandal Widgets](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Widget.html) and the widget is registered with `widget.registerKind('userinfo')` at application startup, I believe that you should be using something like this.

```
<div>
    UserInfo: <div id="1" data-bind="userinfo: {data: $root.userInfo}"></div>
    UserInfo-2: <div id="2" data-bind="userinfo: {data: $root.userInfo}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't registered widget at application startup. is there a way without registering in application startup ?

Comment: I believe that it just needs to registered before the page with the widget is loaded and bound to.